# See list of all SQL Queries run on server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there a query I can run which will display all the queries which have been run on the server within a date range for a specific database?

I need to find out what parameter values were passed to a Stored Procedure which was executed last week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

The only way this can be done is if a monitoring process is set up *in advance*.

Monitoring a database, e.g. through SQL Profiler, has a performance impact, so one should be wary about using this against a live system for prolonged periods.

A better way to monitor this kind of activity, would be by use of logging from the calling code.

Answer (score 2):

try the below:

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/03/sql-server-2005-last-ran-query-recently-ran-query/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added a WHERE clause to this query to filter between the time I need. It's displaying my Stored Procedure several times, but its display 'CREATE PROCEDURE...' rather than 'EXEC dbo.ProcedureName....'.

Comment: Note that [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) is based on the query plan *cache*, so might not include all SQL statements executed between oldest and newest rows.

Comment: you were talking about query not store proc:-)
SqlServer does not keep a track of what you need.  You need to actively capture this,  the simplest is start a profiler

Comment: I think executing a stored procedure is a query? Thanks Massimiliano :)

Comment: this doesn't store dynamic sql or the parameters used, or the runtime of each query, but does have some quite nice aggregate stats (total executions runtime and reads by query plan, when the plan was created, and when it was last used) in situations where the query plan can be reused. -- see discussion at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35703/find-all-the-queries-executed-recently-on-a-database