# How to see list of remote query executions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am using the latest version of SQL Server Express. I have installed it in one machine, and am executing queries on it from a remote machine diagrammatically. In the machine where SQL Server Express is installed, I ran this query to see what remote queries were executed :

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

this is from this post : [See list of all SQL Queries run on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842862/see-list-of-all-sql-queries-ran-on-server)

But it seems to list only the locally-executed queries. How do I see the list of all the queries (including those that I executed in this DB from the remote machine). Or, is it that, because some of my remote queries failed to execute (they returned `sql server error code 102 severity 15`), will they not be listed here? If yes, then how do I see what queries were 'attempted to be executed'? (so that I can see what error was there in the remote query even if failed to execute)

Comment: Those queries won't be shown as they didn't even compile. Have you access to SQL Profiler?

Comment: Are you using ADO.NET to execute the queries?

Comment: Actually you said "diagramatically". Not sure what that means, though. My mind read it "programatically".

Comment: Sorry marceln, it is 'programmatically'. @MartinSmith, nope, since it is the Express version, it doesn't have a profiler. Anjlabs seemed to have a free profiler, but now it's not free. Any free profiler? or Any other way to list the queries ?